# Distinct select from sql number column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a sql column that has codes 4 digit codes using letters and numbers.  My question is how to do I select all the rows with in that column that start with a number.

example data would be :

```
Codes
afif
eafea
5fea
6few
cesa
25aa
```

I want to select rows 5fea, 6few,25aa

I've tried doing something like

```
select 
   left(Codes,4)
from tableX
where year = 2013
   and Codes between 1 and 9
```

Comment: what is your pattern?? how many digits are fixed from left

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to get all that start with any digit, you could try

```
SELECT Codes FROM tableX where Codes LIKE '[0-9]%'
```

See more from [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Comment: I just tried that and still got U's and B's for some odd reason

Comment: Do you mean you got strings that started with U's or B's?

Comment: @TroyBryant that won't return values *beginning* with U or B. Did you add an extra percent?

Comment: +1 anyway as this is sargable and can be converted to a range seek.

Comment: yea i had extra percent in there

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT Codes FROM TableX WHERE LEFT(Codes, 1) LIKE '[0-9]'
```

Basically the first character of `Codes` must be in the range 0 to 9 to be returned.